# Is it "mutual causation" or "mutual causality"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I'd like to know what is more common and idiomatic: **mutual causation** or **mutual causality**. Is there any difference? I have seen both usages. Some of the definitions of causation and causality overlap (they are presented as synonyms). Does the choice of the expression depend on the context?

It refers to a situation where A affects B, and B affects A.

Comment: Hi Zain.  The choice depends on the intended meaning.  Can you give an example sentence?  It is probably better not to use to use the phrase at all, but I'd have to know what you actually want to say.

Comment: So those are examples that you have found.  Great, I'll add them to your question.  Now what do **you** want to say?

Comment: For the life of me, I can't see any difference between the two words; in meaning, nuance, registry, domain or context. But there are resources all over the internet saying that "causation" is about a particular cause and effect relationship as well as the abstract notion, while "causality" refers only to the abstract notion, so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: http://www.digitalpeirce.fee.unicamp.br/p-cauhul.htm

Comment: The two do have a different sense of meaning to my mind: "causation" referring to the action of the verb, and "causality" representing the principle or concept itself.

Comment: In philosophy it matters which you use; in general speech it doesn't and I'd use the more common, *causation*. But words often have different meanings in philosophy compared to in marketing, so you shouldn't expect the same answer to apply to both. If you want to ask specifically about philosophical usage, you could try Philosophy SE (or, better still, look in a dictionary of philosophy.)

Comment: @StuartF Also in statistics. A statistician (or scientist, etc.) might say that an experiment has demonstrated "causation" (as opposed to mere "correlation"), but I've never heard of an experiment demonstrating "causality".

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 3):

"Causality" refers to the *concept* of causes and effects, and is not used to refer to any specific cause and effect, so "mutual causality" does not make sense. It would be like saying "90-degree angularity" (incorrect) instead of "90-degree angle" (correct).

"Mutual causation" is correct but I would not consider it idiomatic. "Causation" is a pretty uncommon word in spoken or written English, outside of technical discussions of law, philosophy or science, as well as the well-known aphorism "correlation does not imply causation." Also, in a scientific context "reciprocal causation" is much more often used than "mutual causation."

Some idiomatic ways of expressing this concept are:

- A and B have *synergy;* they *synergize* with each other; they are *synergistic.*
- A and B are *complementary;* they *complement* each other.
- The processes A and B *feed in* to each other; they demonstrate *positive feedback;* they are in a *feedback loop.*
- The beings A and B are *symbiotic;* they have *symbiosis* with each other.
- A and B are *mutually reinforcing* or *mutually supporting.*

Answer (score 3):

These are not commonly used terms, so being a native English speaker does not necessarily help to answer this question. However, the words 'causality' and 'causation' alone have distinct meanings:

- **Causality** is the name for the *concept* or principle that everything has a cause.
- **Causation** is the name of the *process* of causing something to happen.

Based on these definitions I would expect a book or an educational course that explained the principle to be titled 'Mutual Causality', but any evidence in support of the principle would be an example of *mutual causation*.

Answer (score -1):

According to [dictionary.com](https://dictionary.com), ***['causality'](https://dictionary.com/browse/causality)*** is one of the definitions of ***['causation'](https://dictionary.com/browse/causation)***, so '***mutual causation***' is the better option, and is more idiomatic.

Comment: @zain this is a different answer, the one I deleted answered ‘***mutual causality***’. This one answers ‘***mutual causation***’

Comment: In your earlier (now deleted) answer, you said "from Google", and a commenter said you should include a better reference. Here, you have done the same thing (i.e., you have Googled the two terms and pasted the definitions into your answer), but you have omitted a reference altogether. The correct way to handle this is to say "from Oxford" (if you look carefully at the Google results, you'll see that Google is pulling from an Oxford dictionary). Also, it's best not to delete a downvoted answer and post a new one; instead, it's better to improve the old one and see if the downvotes get reversed.